# error, in casting (char *) to (const void *)

Tags: c

I trying to make a function that works as memchr(3) in C programming, as shown.

```
void    *ft_memchr(const void *ptr, int ch, size_t count)
{
    while (((char *)ptr)[0] != ch && --count)
        (char *)ptr++;
    if (((int *)ptr)[0] == ch)
        return ((void *)ptr);
    return (NULL);
}
```

When I compile, it spits out an error like this.

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -c ft_memchr.c -o ft_memchr.o  

ft_memchr.c:6:3: error: expression result unused [-Werror,-Wunused-value]  
(char *)ptr++;  
^       ~~~~~  

1 error generated.
```

I also tried on changing the code like this,

```
(char *)ptr++;// former
((char *)ptr)++;// latter
```

but spits out the different error.

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -c ft_memchr.c -o ft_memchr.o
ft_memchr.c:6:4:
error: assignment to cast is illegal, lvalue casts are not supported
                ((char *)ptr)++;
                ~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Comment: `(char *)ptr++` -> `((char *)ptr)++`. Or just declare a variable at the top and then use that to avoid casting all over  the place: `char *cptr = ptr;`

Comment: Thank you. I declared cptr, and the error dissapeared. I still haven't figured out why my code spit out error though.

Comment: Please clarify your question. The error in the title is different to the error shown in the body of the question.

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted. I changed the title.

Comment: Did you try to cast to `const char *`?